# How to sum columns from with a same record value in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to sql. I have a table called emSaldos that has records with three fields IMPORTE,N_COMP,t_COMP. I need only one combination of N_comp and t_comp, so I need to delete all that are repeated minus one, whose IMPORTE field has to have the SUM of the IMPORTE field of other records with the same n_comp and t_comp combination. I can't think correctly of to do this on t-sql, any help? Ask me again if you didnt understand.

UPDATE: I managed to do the first part, sum all the IMPORTE from the registers with the same n_comp,t_comp, I only need to delete the repeat records now.

UPDATE:What I expect is to get one record for each t_comp and n_comp combination on whose IMPORTE field is the sum of all the record which had the same t_comp and n_comp combination. I managed to do the first part, all IMPORTE fields have the sum of all records that had the same combination, now I only need to delete all records that have the same combination of t_comp and n_comp minus one.

Comment: will importe ever be negative?  if not then you can find the max of each combination of N_COMP and t_comp and delete all but the max.  If not, then this approach will not work as the max will not necessarily be the record you want to keep...

Comment: Importe my be negative, but I also have to make sure that the record that stays has the sum of it and the records i deleted.

Comment: You have a problem then.  if the aggregate and the values which constitute the aggregate are in the same table and you have the possibility of negative numbers, I know of no such way to remove duplicates as the aggregate record may appear to be a duplicate. Furthermore how do we know what is and is not a duplicate and not just the two valid values? (Sample for those playing along... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b084f/7/0)

Comment: Both are valid values, the only difference was the IMPORTE but I summed it, so now they're the same, I only need to delete all that are the same but one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(IMPORTE) as 'importe', N_COMP,t_COMP
into #temp 
from table 
group by N_COMP,t_COMP;
delete table;
insert into table (importe, N_COMP, t_COMP) 
select (importe, N_COMP, t_COMP) from #temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a simple aggregation query:

```
select sum(IMPORTE) as IMPORTE, N_COMP, t_COMP
from emSaldos s
group by N_COMP, t_COMP;
```

This returns a result where `IMPORTE` is the sum of all the `IMPORTE` values for each combinations of the other two fields.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

```
select sum(IMPORTE), N_COMP,t_COMP
from table 
group by N_COMP,t_COMP
```

Comment: could you describe your question clearly ? Please show your expect result on your question

Answer (score 0):

This should delete all records from emSaldos that do not have the max importe for each group of N-Comp and T_comp leaving only 1 record for each N_comp/T_Comp.  However, if you have negative numbers, this will not meet your need.

```
Delete from emSaldos S
LEFT JOIN (Select max(importe) as importe, n_comp, T_Comp FROM emSaldos GROUP BY n_comp,T_Comp) S2 
 on S.Importe = S2.Importe 
and S.N_Comp  = S2.N_comp
and S.T_Comp = S2.T_COMP
WHERE SS2.Importe is null
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have negatives, and also I need the records that stay to have the sum of all other records with the same n_comp,t_comp combination.